# Does anybody know what this means?

Tags: char, base64, decode, cryptarithmetic-puzzle

My co-worker just asked me to find out what something means. and I don't know.

Does anybody know what 'Y29taW5nIHRvIHRoZSBvZmZpY2UgdG9kYXkg' means?

hint : take a closer look at the charset of the string

Comment: It's base 64 encoding. It means "coming to the office today ".

Answer (score -3):

Y29taW5nIHRvIHRoZSBvZmZpY2UgdG9kYXkg decodes to "coming to the office today" in Base64 format

[Base 64 decoding](https://www.base64decode.org/)